# Update string in a PHP without page refresh, AJAX type function

Tags: php, ajax

I would like to see if there's a way to perform similar task in PHP.  I utilized javascript to update the string in the 'boldStuff' id with another string, in this case the user's name, when submit button is clicked.  The important concept is that the page or section containing the 'boldStuff' updates without the page refreshing.  Basically, i would like to perform a similar function in PHP without the page refreshing everytime someone clicks the submit button.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function displayMessage(firstName, lastName) {
document.getElementById('boldStuff').innerHTML = firstName + " " + lastName; //prints

}
</script>

<p>Welcome to my website, <b id='boldStuff'>dude</b> </p> 
</br>

<div id="hg">

<form>
First name:
<input type="input" name="yourName" /> </br>
First name:
<input type="input" name="yourLast" /> </br>
<input
type="button"
onclick="javascript:displayMessage(form.yourName.value, form.yourLast.value)"
value="Display Message" />
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. You want to update `boldStuff` without page refreshing, right? Isn't that what the code does now?

Comment: spend a bit time on google to searching that or also on the top of the stackoverflow you will get the result that you want.

Comment: If you want to update server side things without refreshing the page, then you most likely want AJAX. You should look up JQuery too, it makes AJAX _much_ easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your html file should be simular to:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#submit").submit(function() {
    // we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
    var fname     = $('#fname').attr('value');
    var lname     = $('#lname').attr('value');
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: "fname="+ fname +"&amp; lname="+ lname,
            success: function(){
                $('form#submit').hide(function(){$('div.success').fadeIn();});

            }
        });
    return false;
    });

});
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="submit" method="post">
<fieldset><legend>Enter Information</legend> 
<label for="fname">Client First Name:</label>
 <input id="fname" class="text" type="text" name="fname" size="20" />
  <label for="lname">Client Last Name:</label> 
  <input id="lname" class="text" type="text" name="lname" size="20" /> 
  <button class="button positive">  Add Client </button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<div class="success" style="display: none;">Client has been added.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and ajax.php

```
<?php

    include ("../../inc/config.inc.php");

    // CLIENT INFORMATION
    $fname        = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['fname']));
    $lname        = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['lname']));

    $addClient  = "INSERT INTO clients (fname,lname) VALUES ('$fname','$lname')";
    mysql_query($addClient) or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

I copy this code from [enter link description here][1]

[1]: http://www.ryancoughlin.com/2008/11/04/use-jquery-to-submit-form/  and I tested.

Answer (score 1):

PHP runs on the server, not in the browser. There is no way for it to interact directly with a page loaded in a browser. PHP can generate a page and send it to the browser to display, but that's the end of the story. If you want to manipulate the page without reloading, you need a client-side technology. This means Javascript in 99.9% of cases.

If you need something from the server, you can use Javascript to fetch the result of a PHP script and insert it on your page without reloading but, even though PHP can be involved, all of the client-side actions will be performed by Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.  Your answer does make logical sense.  I'm a grad IT student, and unfortunately this is not a kind of stuff they teach in the classroom.  I will research deeper into Javascript and php collaboration.